# Where to find legacy Apple docs?

Tags: macos

I have a piece of old Mac OS X code that I'm to recompile for the modern version of the OS. The code uses functions like `GetIntlResource` or `SysBeep` and the compiler complains that they have been deprecated long ago (in Apple years, apparently). I'd be happy to replace the calls with something more modern, but I cannot find any docs on these functions. (I expect the docs to say something like “deprecated, use `FooBar` instead.”) Same for functions like `CreateWindowFromNib` and such; these are worse than deprecated, they are not even there. Searching developer.apple.com or Google produces no useful results.

Is there a way to find documentation on old Apple APIs to understand at least what they were doing?

**Update:** Found what they call a [legacy library](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/navigation/); not searchable (e.g. you cannot search by a function name), but it's better than nothing.

**Update 2:** The thing was originally compiled for Mac OS X v10.4, I think. If I configure the build to target that version, it works fine without any warnings. Naturally, a 64-bit build is not possible, but that is expected. I guess it's OK to close this question, since I found the cold storage myself.

Comment: Is it Mac OS X or before?

Comment: The [help/on-topic] clearly says that questions asking us to locate an off-site resource are off-topic.

Comment: @KenWhite I think this is on-topic because he's looking for authoritative, first-party documentation. The FAQ says, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." — links to developer.apple.com are not spam, and there's one unique best answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: By definition, answering such a question is a link-only answer to an off-site location, which are also not acceptable here. The question is IMO off-topic.

Comment: @KenWhite So… don't answer with only a link.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: What would be more *meaningful, useful information* to add to an answer to a question asking for a link? *Here you go:* or *You can find them here*?

Comment: @KenWhite See my answer. More meaningful and useful than a link: directions for searching and identifying the authoritative resource.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: OK; you turned it into a book recommendation (which is also off-topic here).

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not recommending a book, I'm stating the name of the pre-Internet official API documentation. There's a big difference. The problem with recommending books is that there are competing authors people might have different preferences. Re-read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular calls you mention date from before OS X. At that time, the core of Mac programming documentation was the *Inside Macintosh* series of books. These are available in the "retired documents library" that you linked, however the search bar there seems to skip over them.

Try using Google queries like `"Inside Macintosh" SysBeep`. It's not foolproof, but you can find the given APIs here:

- `SysBeep` in [*Inside Macintosh: Macintosh Toolbox Essentials*](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/mac/pdf/MacintoshToolboxEssentials.pdf)
- `GetIntlResource` in [*Inside Macintosh: Text*](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/mac/pdf/Text.pdf)

*Essentials* serves as a sort of in-depth overview and refers to other books… these were written before the Internet took off. The library of books is pretty much self-contained, but it only captures a snapshot of the mid-1990's. I don't suppose that a rehashed version for OS X 10.4 survives, if it ever existed. I only recall them publishing lists of pre-OS X routines that were blessed for forward compatibility.